# AesManaged throwing “Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" depending on length of string to decode

Tags: .net, encryption

I know there is plenty of this questions with answers around but I have spent hours and hours googleing and have tried all suggestions that I have found.

I know very little about cryptography but I needed a very simple encryption/decryption for strings. Well, it works for some strings' length but not for others, throwing a "Padding is invalid...". I am using the encryption/decryption to store passwords. Thus, some passwords are fine but other fail when decrypted. The key and vector are hardcoded and always the same.

Here are the functions:

```
String^ EncryptString(String^ stringtoencrypt,String^ EnKey,String^ EnVector)
{
    String^ myreturn="";
    array<Byte>^ mykey= UnicodeEncoding::Unicode->GetBytes(EnKey);
    array<Byte>^ myvector= UnicodeEncoding::Unicode->GetBytes(EnVector);
    array<Byte>^ inBlock = UnicodeEncoding::Unicode->GetBytes(stringtoencrypt);

    System::Security::Cryptography::AesManaged^ myaes= gcnew AesManaged();
    myaes->Padding=PaddingMode::PKCS7;

    ICryptoTransform^ myaest= myaes->CreateEncryptor(mykey,myvector);
    array<Byte>^ outBlock = myaest->TransformFinalBlock(inBlock, 0, inBlock->Length);
    myreturn = UnicodeEncoding::Unicode->GetString(outBlock);
    return myreturn;
}


String^ DecryptString(String^ stringtodeencrypt,String^ EnKey,String^ EnVector)
{
    String^ myreturn="";
    array<Byte>^ mykey= UnicodeEncoding::Unicode->GetBytes(EnKey);
    array<Byte>^ myvector= UnicodeEncoding::Unicode->GetBytes(EnVector);
    array<Byte>^ inBlock = UnicodeEncoding::Unicode->GetBytes(stringtodeencrypt);//UnicodeEncoding::Unicode->GetBytes(stringtodeencrypt);
    System::Security::Cryptography::AesManaged^ myaes= gcnew AesManaged();
    myaes->Padding=PaddingMode::PKCS7;
    myaes->KeySize=128;

        MemoryStream^ encryptedStream = gcnew MemoryStream();
    ICryptoTransform^ myaest= myaes->CreateDecryptor(mykey,myvector);

    CryptoStream^ decryptStream = gcnew CryptoStream(encryptedStream, myaest, CryptoStreamMode::Write);
    decryptStream->Write(inBlock, 0, inBlock->Length);
    decryptStream->FlushFinalBlock();

    array<Byte>^ outBlock = encryptedStream->ToArray();
        encryptedStream->Close();
    decryptStream->Close();

    //originally it was like this
    //array<Byte>^ outBlock = myaest->TransformFinalBlock(inBlock, 0, inBlock->Length);
    myreturn = UnicodeEncoding::Unicode->GetString(outBlock);
    return myreturn;
}
```

The only difference between one working and one not working is the length of the string. I have tried with different encoding for the Byte arrays, with TransformFinalBlock, with Streams, flushing them, with different keys,...

Why is it failing depending on length of string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   myreturn = UnicodeEncoding::Unicode->GetString(outBlock);
```

A string cannot store arbitrary binary data, not every byte value matches a Unicode codepoint and the data can get corrupted when the string is normalized.  Significant odds as well for a crash when the binary data happens to match a utf-16 surrogate.

You must encode it so this won't happen, base64 encoding is the common choice:

```
   myreturn = Convert::ToBase64String(outBlock);
```

And use Convert::FromBase64String() when you decrypt to recover the `array<Byte>^` from the string.

Comment: Thank you! I have applied the change you propose to the encoding function, which is the one storing the password to a file. The decoding function then uses 'array<Byte>^ inBlock = Convert::FromBase64String(stringtodeencrypt);' when recovering the encrypted text. Now, as an emergency until I finish this, is there a way to store the passwords so that the current function can decrypt them? I mean the ones stored as Unicode...

Comment: Looks like I also know little about encoding text!:)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your tip. I could have not found it in ages myself. Sorry to chase you with this but I am sure you have the answer for this: Is there a way I can re-store the passwords so that the old function (reading the string as 'UnicodeEncoding::Unicode->GetBytes(stringtodeencrypt)') can decrypt them? It is just a temporal solution until I can deploy the new function...